# Why does concatenating this string before adding it as a parameter to a recursive function cause stack overflow?

Tags: javascript, recursion, memory-management, permutation

```
function permToN(charList, returnLen, base) {
  if (base.length === returnLen) {
    console.log(base)
  } else {
    for (let char of charList) {
      base += char
      permToN(charList, returnLen, base)
    }
  }
}

permToN(['a', 'b', 'c'], 2, "");
```

Hi was brushing up on some algorithms and this baffled me.  In the above code the problem errs out with Maximum call Stack size exceeded.

***However - if I remove the line `base += char` and make the recursive function call instead with `permToN(charList, returnLen, base + char)` concatenating the string inside the function param the function works as intended - no stack overflow*** I am pretty baffled why that small change causes stack overflow.  I think I may not understand how the memory is functioning under the hood ? Would greatly appreciate anyone who can explain difference in performance btwn the functions.  Below is the function with the concatenation occurring in the params of the function call which works as intended.  The above function causes stack overflow.  Do not understand the fundamental difference here. thank you!

```
function permToN(charList, returnLen, base) {
  if (base.length === returnLen) {
    console.log(base)
  } else {
    for (let char of charList) {
      permToN(charList, returnLen, base + char)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The values being passed for the 3rd argument to `permToN` are different between the 2 versions of the code (except for the first iteration).

Comment: Yes, thank you - My quest is RE why the values are different and why concatenating in the param of the function call (in the second version of the function ) why would that work rather than just concatenating the value before passing to the param.  What in that minor change makes them be treated differently ?

Comment: I would think seeing what the values are would make it clear: the first one keeps making `base` longer, the second just changes the last character.

Comment: The values are the same per my logic.  It is string concatenation and assignment written two slightly different ways.  `base += char` means add one char to  the base string then assign that value to base.   `base + char passed in as a param` means adds on char to the base and assign that value to param base.   Anyway - I am kind of baffled - hence - asking but that was my understanding.   I would try to console log out the first version but it overflows memory.   Maybe I will explore this further.  Appreciate your feedback.

Comment: `base` is not the same in the *second* iteration, and with each subsequent iteration, the difference becomes more stark.